# running django tests against remote server

Tags: django, testing

I've built up a suite of unit tests for my django project -- running them against the local test server works fine.

Now that I've deployed the code to a production environment, I would like to reuse those tests against a remote server (mostly to catch any config bugs etc).

```
django-admin test ...
```

doesn't seem to offer any options for specifying the target server, and I would rather not rewrite/fork the tests.

Is there a good way of running django unit tests against a remote server? I couldn't find anything in the docs / SO / google..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not what unit tests are for.

Unit tests don't run "against" a particular server. In fact, no server is really involved at all - the test client simulates a server when you do `client.get(url)`, but actually calls the code directly.

If you want to test your code running in different environments, you need to use an integration test framework - something like [robotframework](http://code.google.com/p/robotframework/) in conjunction with Selenium, for example.